# Model being received empty in the controller after post

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my api Asp.Net Core 3.1, I have some controllers that receive viewModel, but when I post, the model arrives empty in the controller.

My ClientViewModel:

```
public class ClientViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<OperationViewModel> Operations { get; set; }
}
```

My Add ClientController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ClientViewModel>> Add(ClientViewModel clientViewModel)
    {
    //...
    }
```

Post Json:

```
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Bradesco",
    "operations":[]
  }
```

This happens to me on any controller that receives a model, put, post. I don't know what can be.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you post the related HTML as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't have `ApiController` attribute on controller so it tries to parse data in request as form data instead of JSON.

Either specify in client model `[FromBody]` attribute or add `[ApiController]` in controller which comes with other fancy functionalities.

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the FromBody attribute in the controller method

```
[HttpPost("/my-endpoint")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ClientViewModel>> Add([FromBody] ClientViewModel clientViewModel)
{
  //...
}
```

The from body attribute does exactly that. Takes the data and assuming you have the correct model (which you do) binds it to the model